# Please add Auth0 to list of identity providers

Tags: azure-web-app-service

A reasonable list of providers is available but adding Auth0 will open the possibilities up. Auth0 is not only excellent but acts as a proxy to a very large list of providers. Plus they are just down the road to you guys :)

Important to me is the ability to use a custom authentication UI and their database storage. Otherwise I have to roll my own. My users do not have any existing accounts (including email) and so need a simple username / password experience (as horrible this might be for most of us)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the Azure Uservoice.

Comment: Are you asking SO to added Auth0 to the auth providers they support or are you asking Azure Web Sites to add Auth0 providers? If you are asking azure websites for auth0, you may want to go to them directly.

Comment: I also found this - it may be useful - https://auth0.com/docs/azure-tutorial

Comment: @DaveShaw I followed the instructions on the post on (per-route authorisation)[https://auth0.com/blog/Authenticate-Azure-Mobile-Services-apps-with-Everything-using-Auth0/] which trigger my question. I to split it out form my other questions. If SO is for questions and UV for requests then I agree with you. Thanks

Comment: I'm asking azure website to add Auth0 to list of providers - that's why I used the azure-app-services tag. Sorry if is not clear. How would I ask then directly? SO seems to be the way they prefer. I'd rather go to GitHub :)

Comment: @ioneyed Thanks - that's interesting but not quite the same thing as azure-web services adding to their directly supported providers. At least Autho zero have updated their docs now. This is even better https://auth0.com/blog/Authenticate-Azure-Mobile-Services-apps-with-Everything-using-Auth0/

Answer (score 0):

Although we like questions on Stack Overflow (so we can get the community involved - there are a lot of people that know about Azure stuff and are willing to share!), feature requests should go on UserVoice for all Azure properties.  The link is here: https://feedback.azure.com

Comment: Got it. In fact i did put it there back in August., so it appears I'm simply repeating myself here due t oanother related question ;) See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/15637701-add-auth0-to-app-service-supported-auth-providers