# Can we dIsplay custom UI for URL Authorization Rules?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My use authentication case is a little unusual as explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694722/please-add-auth0-to-list-of-identity-providers) 'URL Authorization Rules' is just what I'd like to use rather than pass JWTs around and check the claims myself. The most important thing is I have a custom accessible UI for authentication so the current list of  `unauthenticated_action` appears to be inadequate.

I have a Web SPA frontend with a Functions backend so I think I could use the 401 response to detect the need to get the user to authenticate and then retry. Does that seem workable to you?

Alternatively, a `unauthenticated_action` of `redirectToUrl` would appear to be a useful addition for myself and others. The would return 301 with the specified URL. That would obviously require a argument in the JSON/YML.

Comment: Please try to have a look at this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management) and this tutorial http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html

Comment: Thanks Bruce, that looks interesting and should help. It's certainly a clean pattern.